# Alternating negative and positive sequence using recursion

Tags: recursion, sequence

Finding the nth number in a basic increasing sequence of integers such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... is not complicated to write as a recursive function.

For a sequence of integers that alternates between positive and negative (i.e. 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7....) it is more complicated to find the nth number recursively. How would this be expressed as a recursive function? Dealing with the negative numbers is the most difficult part for me.

Comment: you could also look at x(n-2) if you didn't like the signs... ultimately stuff like this is better off as x=f(n) though

Comment: Hint: if you're too confused when dealing with mixed positive/negative numbers, then rather than dealing with mixed positive/negative numbers directly, you can deal with the absolute value and the sign separately.

Comment: Or another way: do a few examples by hand. What's the relation between -4 and +5? Try to fill in the dots to make the equality true: `5 = ... (-4) ...`. What's the relation between +7 and -8? Try to fill in the dots: `-8 = ... 7 ...`. Now try to fill the dots more generally: `x(n+1) = ... x(n) ...`